# Migration Tips moving from ECL IDE to VSCode

Tags: hpcc-ecl

I have been using the Windows based ECL IDE for 11 years, but would now like to migrate to using the Visual Studio Code with the ECL extension. Is there any available documentation, or can you share any migration tips and best practices? Thanks!

I have been to the marketplace web page [text](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hpcc-systems.ecl) but perhaps a clear step-by-step list of installation steps would be great.

Answer (score 2):

I found this useful information from another ECL developer using VSCode:

**Getting Started with Visual Studio Code Editor and ECL**

1. **Locate** and **install** the appropriate ECL Client Tools version from [hpccsystems.com](https://hpccsystems.com)
2. **Install** VSCode if you haven’t yet done so. You can install to Windows, Linux, or Mac platforms. Here is the link:

https://code.visualstudio.com/download

For Windows 10, I used the 64-bit Users Install for Windows.

3. In VSCode, **open** the command palette (ctrl+shift+p) and select *Install Extension*. Enter "ecl" to filter the available extensions and **choose** ecl.

**HPCC Cluster Configuration**

4. **Click on Debug Icon** in VSCode (located on the Side Bar)
5. **File** > **Add Folder to Workspace** – Add "My Files" folder: (C:\Users\Public\Documents\HPCC Systems\ECL\My Files)
6. **Click on Gear Icon** near top (Configure or Fix launch.json). If asked, select the ECL environment.
7. **Modify** configuration as follows:

VSCode will supply a default profile for ECL and the users can manually modify the following as needed:
Example:

```
        "name": "play.hpccsystems.com",
        "type": "ecl",
        "request": "launch",
        "protocol": "https",
        "serverAddress": "play.hpccsystems.com",
        "port": 18010,
        "targetCluster": "thor",
        "rejectUnauthorized": false,
        "resultLimit": 100,
        "timeoutSecs": 60,
        "user": "Bob",
        "password": "(IfNeeded)"
```

8. Save your changes (**File** > **Save**)

Running your first ECL file

9. **Open** a test ECL file – (Example – Hello.ecl)
10. **Click on the arrow** in the upper right of the editor to compile/run the ECL file
11. To see the output, look at the *Output* tab in the Panel view below the editor.

Happy Coding!